# Upgrading postgresql database on heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Heroku provide [instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases) for provisioning a new postgresql database, which involves a command of the form

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:standard-0
```

where the text after postgresql: is a key to the level of database. Presumably standard-0 is the lowest level of standard.  It took me about ten minutes, using the web interface to be reasonably sure that hobby-basic is the key for the highest level of basic. Can someone please provide a table that gives the key for each of the database levels so we do not have to guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different levels, along with the keys are available in the [Heroku Postgres add-on page](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql).

You can install the add-on directly from there, or use one of the keys you can extract from the anchor part of the URI (e.g. for `https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql#standard-6` it is `standard-6`).

Comment: Thank you. It would be useful if Heroku updated their instructions at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases to include this information.